# External USB Hard Disk detect as Local Hard Disk

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, external-hard-drive

Yesterday, I convert my External Hard disk from FAT32 to NTFS using "EASEUS Partition Master". Today, my external hard disk was detected as Local disk on my Windows 7 PC.

I can still use the drive perfectly.  However, I can't do "safely remove USB device" anymore since it was detected as local disk.

What should I do?

Comment: Not an answer since I am not sure(and I am Curious). But would removing with PC powered off be sufficient?

Answer (score 1):

You should still be able to "eject" the drive. Take a close look at the icons provided in your lower right-hand region of your screen. One of them is likely for safely removing devices.

Something nice about using NTFS instead of FAT32 on a USB drive is that NTFS is journaled, which means it keeps a log of everything it's doing in such a way that if you "uncleanly" remove the device, the chances of file system corruption are much much lower. Still, write caching and the like could factor in, so safely removing the device is certainly a good thing to do.

If my suggestion doesn't help, maybe go in to "My Computer" and see if "eject" is an option when you right-click over the drive's icon.

Comment: Unfortunately no, I couldn't select any option to remove the drive. In my computer, the drive is sitting right next to C: drive. It treats it as internal hard disk completely.

Answer (score 0):

I just read about the Lexart Bootit USB format utility.  It includes the ability to flip the removable disk bit on a drive.  I've not trested so don't try it unless the disk is backed up.

[More info here](http://www.ehow.com/how_5871300_make-flash-drive-appear-hdd.html)